# How to Binding to subcontrols from main

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext

I have a usercontrol which displays a List. The List have 2 columns, Address and Value.

I want to use the UserControl in main

```
 <SubControl:MonitorColumn x:Name="monitorCol01" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding ListPg01}" />
```

and in main's behind..

```
  public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        manager = new MELManager();
        DataContext = manager ;

        monitorCol01.DataContext = manmanager.ListPg01;

    }
```

Also I have a property for DataClass that has Address and Value. But SubWindow(MonitorColumn)'s DataContext filled after its Construtor. 
And the data not showed on the listView at all.

The other class gets the data every minute, but the subWindow not Updated.

How can I bind to SubWindow??

Comment: Need more info: What's the `MonitorColumn`? What's the `MELManager`? What's type of `MELManager.ListPg01'? Please edit the question to add relevant things.

Comment: The line `monitorCol01.DataContext = manmanager.ListPg01;` is redundant as the `MonitorColumn.DataContext` is already set via binding: `<MonitorColumn DataContext="{Binding ListPg01}" ... />`. It also removes the binding and may introduce unexpected behavior when the data source changes. Stay with the binding. Setting a property, that has a binding, directly will always remove this binding. The isource of your problem appears to related to the implementation of `MonitorColumn`. To be able to provide help, please post the implentation details.